# Why is my GitHub code search hitting secondary rate limits?

Tags: rest, github, github-api, octokit, github-search

I am searching for GitHub files containing the string "torch." Since, the search API limits searches to the first 100 results, I am searching based on file sizes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602893/github-search-limit-results/47828323#47828323). However, I keep hitting the secondary rate limit. Could someone suggest if I am doing something wrong or if there is a way to optimize my code to prevent these rate limits? I have already looked at [best practices](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/best-practices-for-integrators?apiVersion=2022-11-28) to deal with rate limits. Here is my code -

```
import os
import requests
import httplink
import time

# This for loop searches for code based on files sizes from 0 to 500000 containing the string "torch"
for i in range(0,500000,250):
  print("i = ",i," i + 250 = ", i+250)
  url = "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=torch +in:file + language:python+size:"+str(i)+".."+str(i+250)+"&page=1&per_page=10" 

  headers = {"Authorization": f'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'} ## Please put your token over here

  # Backoff when secondary rate limit is reached
  backoff = 256

  total = 0
  cond = True

  # This while loop goes over all pages of results => Pagination
  while cond==True:
    try:
      

          time.sleep(2)
          res = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
          res.raise_for_status()
          link = httplink.parse_link_header(res.headers["link"])

          data = res.json()
          for i, item in enumerate(data["items"], start=total):
              print(f'[{i}] {item["html_url"]}')

          if "next" not in link:
              break

          total += len(data["items"])

          url = link["next"].target

    # Except case to catch when secondary rate limit has been reached and prevent the computation from stopping
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print("err = ", err)
        print("err.response.text = ", err.response.text)
        # backoff **= 2
        print("backoff = ", backoff)
        time.sleep(backoff)
    # Except case to catch when the given file size provides no results
    except KeyError as error:
      print("err = ", error)

      # Set cond to False to stop the while loop
      cond = False
      continue
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030298/continuously-hitting-the-github-secondary-rate-limit-even-after-following-the-be), it seems like it is a common occurrence. However, I was hoping someone could suggest a workaround.

I have added the tag Octokit, although I am not using that, to increase visibility and since this seems like a common problem.

A big chunk of the above logic/code was obtained through SO answers, I highly appreciate all support from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that search has its primary and secondary rate limiting that is lower than others. For JavaScript, we have a throttle plugin that implements all the recommended best practices. [For search we limit requests to 1 per 2 seconds](https://github.com/octokit/plugin-throttling.js/blob/bde1747ef3f89567b29152ea99f04eaff49a7110/src/index.ts#L25-L30). Hope that helps!