# I keep hitting `You have exceeded a secondary rate limit` on my Github API after just 4 request in a minute when using search

Tags: github, github-api, github-search

I am using the api endpoint `https://api.github.com/search/code?` and just after hitting 3 or 4 request in a minute the response is showing me that I have exceeded my limit.
According to the documentation we have a limit of 30 request in a minute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuously hitting the GitHub secondary rate limit even after following the best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030298/continuously-hitting-the-github-secondary-rate-limit-even-after-following-the-be)

Comment: I am now testing the retry-after header